# Putting levelordertraversal method in tree class in python

Tags: python, tree

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.left=None
    self.right=None
class Tree:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.root=Node(data)
    def levelOrderTraversal(self):
        if self.root==None:
            return
        q,l=[],[]
        q.append(self.root)
        while len(q):
            l.append(q[0].data)
            node=q.pop(0)
            q.append(node.left)
            q.append(node.right)
        print(*l)
tree=Tree(5)
tree.root.left=Node(3)
tree.root.right=Node(6)
tree.root.left.left=Node(2)
tree.root.left.right=Node(4)
tree.levelOrderTraversal()
```

I was expecting the above code to print 5 3 6 2 4 but intead it is giving the error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'.I can't find out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: When `node.left` or `node.right` are `None`, `q.append(node.left)` and the line below it will add `None`s into `q`. `q[0].data` will then cause an error when `None` is at index `0`. You'd need to either check for them and prevent the `None`s from being added in the first place, or check for them before doing `q[0].data`.

Comment: I really forgot to add the conditions there.Thanks for reminding